# Having a different LIBDIR path for Python in Linux

Tags: python, linux, configure

I would like to change the way on Python 2.7 under Linux would load its modules/libraries from. I have tried to change it from the Configure file. Before that, it was like:

> ```
> BINLIBDEST=     $(LIBDIR)/python$(VERSION)
> LIBDEST=        $(SCRIPTDIR)/python$(VERSION)
> INCLUDEPY=      $(INCLUDEDIR)/python$(VERSION)
> CONFINCLUDEPY=  $(CONFINCLUDEDIR)/python$(VERSION)
> LIBP=           $(LIBDIR)/python$(VERSION)
> ```

And I attempted to change it into this:

> ```
> BINLIBDEST=     $(LIBDIR)
> LIBDEST=        $(SCRIPTDIR)
> INCLUDEPY=      $(INCLUDEDIR)
> CONFINCLUDEPY=  $(CONFINCLUDEDIR)
> LIBP=           $(LIBDIR)
> ```

Mainly removing python%(VERSION) from the pathname, so that instead of *lib/python27*, it would simply load its modules from only *lib* folder. However, even if initiating **make** and **make install** works with the changes, the *python* or *python27* Python binary file does not loads the modules from the new path. It falls back with this output:

> ```
> Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
> Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
> Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
> 'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
> ```

**Is** there a way on forcing the Python binary itself (if must) to load up the modules from a new path set by me, instead of the default one as "*$(LIBDIR)/python$(VERSION)*"?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to achieve by getting rid of python$(VERSION) in path but it seems to me as a terrible idea which would get even worse if you try to install python3 along your python2 installation.

Comment: That may be true, but the main idea was not to work with the system-wide Python, but to have a separate, more of a portable version of Python to have its own libraries and modules without, as stated earlier, affecting anything or touching anything from the system-wide Python.

Comment: I see. Anyway, according to docs: "By default, the libraries are searched in prefix/lib/pythonversion and exec_prefix/lib/pythonversion". So probably the best thing you can do is to change the prefix, not the suffix. Consider installing it to `/opt/` directory. You may also have to set `$PYTHONHOME` variable to `/opt/` as it was stated in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do a few changes to python source and recompile, but I'm going to assume that is okay, since this is a pretty non-standard thing to do.

Look at the file `Modules/getpath.c`. The steps python performs to determine the libdir is detailed in the comments in the beginning of the file. You can have a look at the svn repo [here](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Modules/getpath.c). I think you'll want to look at how this define is used:

```
#define PYTHONPATH PREFIX "/lib/python" VERSION ":" \
          EXEC_PREFIX "/lib/python" VERSION "/lib-dynload"
```

I don't think it will be as easy as just changing it to `[...] PREFIX "/lib/:" [...]`, but it will be something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to accomplish something that [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html) doesn't do?

It seems to meet your requirement:

> "...the main idea was not to work with the system-wide Python, but to
>   have a separate, more of a portable version of Python to have its own
>   libraries and modules.."

Comment: I don't think you can do virtualenv on a flash drive, unless it's ext3 formatted...

Comment: @Starbright didn't mention a flash drive but if that's the requirement, there's a specific question for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798704/
And why would it have to be ext3?

Comment: Not specifically ext3 - but it can't be FAT32, which is usually the default - you can't create symlinks on FAT32, which virtualenv requires. Ask me how I know this ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to thank carlpett: I was able to set python search path at runtime: changed from **lib/** to **lib64/** while building Python 2.7.10 in x86_64-my_distro-gnu-linux using gcc 5.1 by **modifying Modules/getpath.c**.

For the record, I tried --libdir at configure time (works for the shared library but not for python modules install paths), modifying Makefile, modifying pyconfig.h, tweaking $PYTHONPATH, $PYTHONHOME, nothing worked.

Just a detail, but the make install does not place correctly the libraries, so you have to do a little cp -af and mv by yourself.

**THANK YOU CARLPETT!!!**

Comment: Was this the only file you had to change? Several 'multi-lib' style patches (for older versions of Python-2.x.x) make changes in about 6 or 7 files, including `Modules/getpath.c`. If it can be done with just changes to Modules/getpath.c, I'd love to know - I have 4 python installations in `/opt/Python/Python-{2.7.9,3.4.3}-{32,64}` now, and anything that requires Python is always a huge pita to get to install/work (because I also didn't want 64-bit libraries in a non-existent `/usr/lib`)

Comment: Hi Chris! You're right, I checked my notes, there was another file to change: at compile time: Modules/Setup (zlib and SSL sections), and at run time: the sysconfig.py module (to adapt modules search, not sure if it has something to do with the libs..).